# SpringBoot truncates last two characters in connection url

Tags: mysql, spring, docker, spring-boot

I get the following error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'aravind'@'192.168.99.1' (using password: YES)
```

But in my application.prpoerties I specified following properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.99.100:3306
spring.datasource.username=aravind
spring.datasource.password=aravind
spring.datasource.name=zeus_spring
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
server.port=8090
```

Spring boot removes the last two zeroes I don't know why. I have a docker container which can be accessed through that IP.

Comment: It might just be that the console log has the ip truncated. It wouldn't be actually trying to access the truncated ip, coz otherwise it wouldn't have said access denied. Since the log says access denied, it means it's trying to to connect to the right ip. Just that the credentials provided are failing authentication.

Comment: Are you able to to connect to the the mysql instance with those creds separately?

Answer (score 0):

Use below property and remove datasource name should work.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.99.100:3306/zeus_spring
```